# onResume called to early when returning from Settings screen

Tags: android

In my app I check if gps is enabled. If not, I send the user to the Settings screen to enable gps.

In my onResume function, I'm requesting information from a server, which is a bit time consuming, and then goes to my next Activity. I'd prefer the user to be stuck at my screen while the information is retrieved. Instead, what I see is the app sits at the Settings screen frozen while the information is gathered, and then goes directly to my next Activity.

```
 protected void onResume() {
        if(gpsIsOn()) {
            obtainLocationStuff();
            startActivity(new Intent(splashActivity.this, mainActivity.class));
        } else {
          launchCloseDialog();
        }

    super.onResume();
}
```

How can I get onResume to be launched when the user is actually returned to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You must use background threads for potentially time consuming operations. Read about [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Cross-activity coordination can't be changed (except in some very rare cases). How activities are coordinated is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities). But in that example one activity starts another. This is the opposite of what you have, but should still demonstrate the rules.

Comment: Perfect. I moved some code around and had my asynctask called upon return. Thank you for the assistance.